# What is a useful pattern to maintaining an object state in a one to many relationship?

Tags: design, c++, design-patterns

I am looking for a design for my application, here are the players(classes) involved.

```
struct Transform {
    // Uses a matrix to transform the position.
    // Also acts acts as the state of a Dialog.
    Position transform(Position p);

    //other methods.
};

struct Dialog {
     // There are multiple dialog for the user to transform the output.

     Transform& t;
     void ChangeTranformation(){t.rotate(360);}
}

struct Algorithm {
    //gives us a position based on an implementation. For example this can return points on a circle or line.

    Transform& t;
    Position m_p;
    Dialog& d;
    Position GetCurrentPosition(){ return t.transform(m_p);}

    //other methods.
}
```

**Properties I need:**

1. Each algorithms has one dialog and each dialog can have many algorithms associated with it.
2. When the user selects an algorithm a dialog associated with that algorithm is displayed.
3. If the user selects a different algorithm then re-selects back the state is restored in the dialog.

Basically I want a good design pattern to maintain the state of the dialog given that many algorithms use it and they can be switched back and forth. Does anyone have any suggestions?

---

**Here is a use case:**

**Dialog1** has a single edit box to control the radius.

**Algorithm1** generates points on a unit circle.

**Algorithm2** is the same as Algorithm1.

The user has selected **Algorithm1** and entered **2** into the edit box. This will generate points on a circle of radius 2.

The user then selects **Algorithm2** and enters **10** into the edit box of **Dialog1**. This will generate points on a circle of radius 10.

Finally **Algorithm1** is selected again. The edit box of **Dialog1** should show **2** and points on a circle of radius 2 should be generated.

Comment: I'm not clear on what's going on here. Just use a reference if you need multiple access to a single datapoint. If you need snapshots in time, then the memento is fine for this.

Comment: I agree with @Telastyn. If you need undo, nesting transformations with a Decorator might come in handy as well.

Comment: Actually, having read it again, I think Chuck's simply looking for the State pattern. But I don't have time to rewrite my answer, so ... deleted.

Comment: @neontapir I do not need to undo a state, I need to randomly change between state based on algorithms selected. Each algorithm has a specific transformation it need to apply to its output (e.g. rotate 10deg in the x axis). The transformation is determined by the dialog(it's stored in a edit box). If the user selects another algorithm they may get a different dialog or the same dialog with the new algorithms transformation in it.

Comment: @ahenderson You're doing a really bad job describing the problem at hand. Be more concrete. From what I understand, you don't need to change the position state itself, just apply transforms consecutively?

Comment: @Telastyn I updated my question with a use case I hope this will make it clearer.

Comment: To me, the use case makes it less clear. It appears that Algorithm1 and Algorithm2 are the same, in that they both generate points on a circle.

Comment: @neontapir The radius is different in this case, I want to know how to allow my design to vary the radius using a dialog. Also, in the general case Algorithm2 could be used to generate points on a ellipse.

Comment: I don't understand. Surely the algorithm is the same, even if the radius is different. Maybe algorithm is a poor name for it. Also, if Algorithm2 is for an ellipse, then you need to provide both the x and y radius, don't you?

Comment: @ahenderson thanks, that helps me understand what is going on, but makes it harder to answer the question. In your example, passing 2 or 10 into the transform/algorithm is simply parameters to those instances. There's no pattern for such straight-forward OOP.

Comment: @pdr Thanks for the initial answer. It turned out the mediator pattern was what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need fancy patterns.  You need to **separate the model from the user interface**.  The algorithms and their current input data form the model.

The dialogs are part of the user interface.  When an algorithm is selected, the corresponding dialog is displayed, showing the current data for the algorithm.  If the user changes the data, that change is passed to the algorithm.

All you need is a one-to-one relationship between algorithms and their input data, and a many-to-one relationship between algorithms and dialogs.

Comment: agreed.. must watch out for "pattern forcing"

Comment: "model-view-controller" is often described as a design pattern, though it's arguable that it's more an architecture than a design pattern.  Still, if you want a fancy pattern...

Answer (score 1):

> Basically I want a good design pattern to maintain the state of the
>   dialog given that many algorithms use it and they can be switched back
>   and forth.

Sounds like a job for [Memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).

> The memento pattern is a software design pattern that provides the
>   ability to restore an object to its previous state...

You're trying to associate the state of a Dialog with an Algorithm. As the current algorithm is being removed, have the current it request a memento from the dialog. The memento is an opaque (from the algorithm's perspective) object that encodes the dialog's state. When the newly selected algorithm is added to the window, it gives the memento that *it* had previously requested (if one exists) to the dialog, and the dialog uses it to configure itself.

That said, preserving the state of the *dialog* is doing things backward. The purpose of a dialog box is to let the user see, and perhaps modify, the data that the program operates on. In your case, it sounds like the algorithms are part of that. When the user changes something in the dialog box, that should cause a corresponding change in the current algorithm, and said change should be stored in someplace other than the controls of the dialog box. If you organize your program that way you can let the selection of the algorithm drive the content of the dialog. This is exactly how you'd do it if you use the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm (or one of it's cousins). If the user changes something in the dialog, that change modifies the algorithm (i.e. the model). If the user selects a different algorithm, the current state of the new algorithm is used to set the values in the dialog.